# SVG updated with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

When I append rect element with x, y, width, height atributes to svg element, the svg was not updated (with jQuery append function).
SVG element is dynamically created with:

```
this.svg = $( document.createElement('svg') );
this.container.append( this.svg ); // this.container is a div element
```

I think my browser (Google Chrome v57.0.2987.133) does not recognize the newly created elements svg and rect because styles tab in developer mode (F12) does not show 'user agent stylesheet' for them.

Append code:

```
var newSvgArea = $( document.createElement( mapArea.shape ) );
// -- SPECIFIC CODE --
newSvgArea.attr( 'data-visual-svg-area-elti', '' + i1 );            
newSvgArea.css('stroke', 'black');
newSvgArea.css('stroke-width', '2px');
newSvgArea.css('fill', 'transparent');
newSvgArea.css('stroke-opacity', '.5');
if (mapArea.shape == 'cicle') {
    newSvgArea.attr( 'cx', mapArea.coordX );
    newSvgArea.attr( 'cy', mapArea.coordY );
    newSvgArea.attr( 'r', mapArea.sizes[0] );
} else if (mapArea.shape == 'rect') {
    newSvgArea.attr( 'x', mapArea.coordX );
    newSvgArea.attr( 'y', mapArea.coordY );
    newSvgArea.attr( 'width', ( mapArea.sizes[0] - mapArea.coordX ) );
    newSvgArea.attr( 'height', ( mapArea.sizes[1] - mapArea.coordY ) );
}
// -- --
this.svg.append( newSvgArea );
```

Generated SVG :

```
<svg style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: block; background-color: transparent; z-index: 10; pointer-events: none;">
    <rect fill="black" x="20" y="29" width="155" height="56"></rect>
    <rect fill="black" x="342" y="84" width="141" height="54"></rect>
    <rect fill="black" x="355" y="172" width="150" height="53"></rect>
    <rect fill="black" x="376" y="272" width="148" height="49"></rect>
    <rect fill="black" x="379" y="338" width="146" height="55"></rect>
    <rect fill="black" x="376" y="414" width="148" height="52"></rect>
    <rect fill="black" x="402" y="533" width="154" height="56"></rect>
    <rect fill="black" x="391" y="627" width="158" height="60"></rect>
    <rect fill="black" x="57" y="511" width="140" height="52"></rect>
    <rect fill="black" x="58" y="578" width="145" height="53"></rect>
    <rect fill="black" x="102" y="656" width="155" height="55"></rect>
</svg>
```

Work fine in jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/4azftdzt/

Comment: Please be more specific about what you expect and what you actually get. Also, you have a typo ("cicle")

Comment: I've edited the post

Comment: The svg element needs to have a specific namespace, and you need to create it with createElementNS

Comment: This does not change anything: /